# automatically power on android when charge is 20% or 10%

Tags: battery, charging, automation, redmi

I know its duplicate on [Power on when charging but only when battery level is greater than 20%](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/210726/power-on-when-charging-but-only-when-battery-level-is-greater-than-20)

but it seems that question has no answer and also android version has changes a lot , I am on Android 10 , need to start my phone when charged to at-least 10 or 20 %  automatically as I am using it for some automation .

Any other way other than physically pressing the power button would be really helpful

Device Redmi Note 5 Pro and its not rooted

Comment: Is your device rooted and which device is it? Please include in question

Comment: With root acess you can run an `init` service in charging mode which is watching charge level. When it reaches the threshold, device can be powered on as explained in this answer of mine: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221384/218526

Comment: fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0  , there is risk of boot loop I read somehwere , if phone is too discharged and on plugged in try to start immediately ?